# How to Add Periodic Image as a Border to a div

Tags: html, css, image, border

Is this possible? I need to add a periodic image(s)/icon(s) or a similar thing to border of a 'div'. Such as a waterpipe traveling the borders of the div.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this css style

```
div
{
-webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari 5 */
-o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;
}
```

[Working Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image)

**Edited**: 
[image]

```
The border-image-slice model
```

You’ll notice that the lines that create the regions are individually numbered. As these imaginary lines intersect, they create the nine areas into which the image will be sliced.
So how do the four numeric values correlate to the image shown above?

- The first value is the distance (in pixels or as a percentage)
  between the topmost edge of the image and line #1.
- The second value is the distance between the rightmost edge and line

  ## 2.
- The third value is the distance between the bottommost edge and line

  ## 3.
- And finally, the fourth value is the distance between the leftmost
  edge and line #4

border.png:
[image]
<sub>(source: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png))</sub>

Comment: [border.png](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png). See Edited Answer @Aristos